# spring_security_last_username

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Can we access "spring_security_last_username" form the Controller instead of jsp?

Answer (score 2):

`SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME` is a session attribute, therefore you can access it from the controller like any session attribute:

```
public ModelAndView controller(..., Session s) {
    String lastUsername = s.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that the [SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html#SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY) is deprecated. As mentioned in its deprecation note, you should use your custom failureHandler to retain any user information.

Comment: Not sure if this will get seen, but the fields of an AuthenticationFailureHandler don't allow access to the username without using deprecated methods as of 3.1.RELEASE.

Comment: How exactly is this supposed to be implemented?  I see the API docs that say you should use implement your own Failure Handler, but I can't find any examples out there about how to do it.  This should be included out of the box as everyone is going to do this, but it appears its not.  Why is this so hard?