# Grails Spring Security Plugin - Username escaping problem

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm currently working with Grails and the Spring Security plugin and trying to implement a password expiration workflow. I've configured the plugin as expected:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.failureHandler.exceptionMappings = [
    'org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException': '/login/passwordExpired'
]
```

and in my passwordExpired action if I call:

```
def username = session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']
```

then in the username the HTML special characters are going to be escaped like

```
my_user => my&#95;user
my-user => my&#45;user
```

Is it possible to turn this escaping off?

Ritesh mentioned here [spring_security_last_username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537252/spring-security-last-username) that the SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME is deprecated, so what else can I use?

For any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The String `'SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME'` isn't deprecated - the old constant with that value is and has been moved with a new name but the same value. So your code will continue to be valid.

Rather than changing things to not escape, you can un-escape easily:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
...
String username = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME'])
```

Comment: I was searching for an unescaping tool for awhile but ... yeah Apache Commons... Thanks!

Comment: FYI in the 2.0+ versions of the plugin, the value isn't escaped now so you must escape it before displaying

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a tool. Use Grails HTML codec:

```
username = session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']?.decodeHTML()
```

Comment: But the choice by Spring Security to store this escaped is very questionable.